# Querying for a polymorphic association on all descendent tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

The following is a bit of a contrived example, but it will get the point across.

Let's say I have the following models.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chapters
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :paragraphs
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Paragraph < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

It is possible to get all comments for a specific book and its descendants with one query? That is, I want all the comments from not just the book model, but also the comments made on the chapters, pages, and paragraphs.  Btw, I realize the Book could have through associations for each of the models, performing an inner join for each, but this would result in 4 queries.

I'm using postgres as a database and Rails 3.2.12.

Answer (score 2):

If you are thinking about eager loading, you can do it from the Book side but not from the Comment side.

```
>> Book.limit(1).includes(:comments).where('comments.id ...') # you'll probably get a book
>> Comment.limit(1).includes(:commentable).where('books.id ...') # you'll get an error

ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError: Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association
```

You can always do the following to get the comments of a book,

```
>> book = Book.first
>> comments = book.comments
>> comments = Comment.where(commentable_type: 'Book', commentable_id: book.id)
```

Comment: I've edited my question to more clearly state the results I've looking for. Specifically, I don't just want the comments of the book instance, but also the comments for the chapters, pages, and paragraphs of that book.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps but I am approaching this from the database side and trying to figure out the best way to deal with this.  I think your issue will be what your db looks like.  If you can work backwards from SQL, that may also help.

This is also an area where solid database design will make your life a lot easier.  Suppose we have the following table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE node_class (
     id int not null unique, 
     node_type label primary key, 
     parent_class int references node_class(id)
);

INSERT INTO node_class (id, node_type, parent_class) 
VALUES (1, 'book', null), (2, 'chapter', 1), (3, 'page', 2), (4, 'paragraph', 3);

CREATE TABLE book_node (
    node_id bigserial primary key,
    node_type int not null,
    parent_class int,
    parent_id int,
    .....
    foreign key (parent_class, parent_id) references book_node(id, node_type)
    foreign key (node_type) references node_class (id),
    foreign key (node_type, parent_class) references node_class(id, parent_class)
);
CREATE TABLE book_comments (
    id bigserial primary key,
    comment_text text not null
);
```

you might have other tables then connecting to the book node table to supply, for example, chapters, page numbers, etc.

Then from there it's pretty easy to generate a query which builds the tree and then joins with comments:

```
WITH RECURSIVE bn_tree (node_id, level, path) as
(
   SELECT node_id, 1, node_id::text
     FROM book_node
    where node_id = ?
UNION ALL
   SELECT n.node_id, level + 1, path || ',' || n.node_id::text
     FROM book_node n
     JOIN bn_tree t ON t.node_id = n.parent
)
SELECT c.* 
  FROM book_comments c
  JOIN bn_tree t ON c.node_id = t.node_id;
```

I think that once you have an idea of how the SQL might work, you might be able to tweak your db design to work better with your app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris. I was hoping someone might give a db answer. However, at the point I am at in this project, I would have to make some serious changes to get this to work (keep in mind this was only an example). What this really tells me is that I can't do what I was hoping, at least from the rails side of things.